# Get the value of a child node from a list of nodes, XML Xpath C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, xpath

I am working on an app that generates Node graphs in a 3D environment using Unity. In order to generate the Nodes, I need to assign them values from a Graphml file.

I dont have much experience with XML, so I'm not sure how anything works. I've done some research and tried many things but I cannot make it work.

This is the problem. I want to access the value of the children of each Node/Edge elements. But I don't know how. This is the code I have. The nodes and edges elements are inside xmlNodeLists.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Globalization;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using Topology;

public class GraphMLReaderThree : MonoBehaviour {

public TextAsset xmlRawFile;

void Start()
{
    string data = xmlRawFile.text;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(data);

    int scale = 2;

    XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("node");
    XmlNodeList edgeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("edge");
    Debug.Log(nodeList.Count);
    XmlNode targetNode = 
    nodeList[0].SelectNodes("//data[@key='author.activity']")[0];
    if (targetNode != null)
    {
        string valor = targetNode.InnerText;
        Debug.Log(valor);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("No nodes found");
    }
}
```

And this is one node of the Graphml. I dont know how to access those Children with the data key thing.

```
    <node id="247983">
        <data key="author.regDate">2010-10-27 23:09:40</data>
        <data key="author.location">Raleigh, NC</data>
        <data key="author.descr">The official twitter account for Red Hat 
        Training, Certification, and Consulting</data>
        <data key="author.pub.descr">Twitter</data>
        <data key="author.country">us</data>
        <data key="author.website">http://www.redhat.com/services</data>
        <data key="author.friends">813</data>
        <data key="author.activity">1</data>
        <data key="author.origId">208736299</data>
        <data key="author.personName">Red Hat Services</data>
        <data key="author.pub.id">11</data>
        <data key="author.tzone">Central Time (US &amp; Canada)</data>
        <data key="author.lon">-78.6386</data>
        <data key="author.name">RedHat_Services</data>
        <data key="author.lat">35.7721</data>
        <data key="author.audience">18155</data>
        <data key="author.eigen.centrality">1.0</data>
        <data key="author.modularity.class">247983</data>
        <data key="author.modularity.size">15</data>
        <data key="coords.x">7.624482</data>
        <data key="coords.y">-11.719869</data>
        <data key="coords.z">-0.9229746</data>
    </node>
```

The problem is, the `Debug.Log` skips to "No Nodes Found". But the Lists are full of node elements and the xPath query is correct. Maybe im not using the correct functions. I expect to get the value 1 of this child in particular "author.Activity" child in particular. And once it works, get all children and assign them to the 3D Node values.

Comment: your code works good and give me a `1`. try your code in simple console app first and then integrate to your main project later

Comment: It works good except in Unity, and I don't know why. But it's fine, I tried another method that works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used XML Linq to create a nested dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication100
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict = doc.Descendants("node")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("id"), y => y.Elements("data")
                    .GroupBy(a => (string)a.Attribute("key"), b => (string)b)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this method. I'm in a hurry to make the project work but I will surely use this when I optimize the code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Xpath doesn't give me the results for some reason. It gives me a Null exception. So I tried with another approach and I made it work. It's a dirty solution, since I will need to add 20 more conditions, but at least it gives me the information from the XML selectively.

For now this works for me until I find an optimized solution. Thanks for the help!

```
void Start () {
    string data = xmlRawFile.text;
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(data);
    XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("node");
    Debug.Log(nodes.Count);

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        string aux=node.Attributes["id"].Value;           
        XmlNodeList childs = node.ChildNodes;

        Debug.Log(childs.Count);
        Debug.Log(aux);
        for(int i=0; i<childs.Count;i++)
        {
            if(childs[i].Attributes["key"].Value == "author.name")
            {
                Debug.Log(childs[i].InnerText);
            }            
        }
    }
}
```