# Comparing Lists of Object

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I am trying to come up with the best solution (a happy medium between a performance-minded approach and not too much code).

For all intents and purposes, the type of object inside of the collections is:

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Given 2 collections (lets call them `defaultCollection` and `specificCollection`) of the `Foo` object type above, I need to compare the collections and end up with a final collection of `Foo` that:

- is a combination of every unique entry from both collections, but only unique from the perspective of the `Id` property of `Foo`
- given any objects that have a matching `Id` between the 2 collections, we should end up with the `specificCollection` version of that particular object

I've started going down the path of converting my collections into `Dictionary<int, Foo>` where the `int` is the `Id` property of the `Foo` instance and doing a Key comparison but I am quickly ending up with 4+ `foreach` loops and am deciding this is probably not a good approach for my problem.  Is there a LINQ approach I can take to this problem to provide better performance and less code than the path I was going down using Dictionaries?

Comment: See my posting earlier today : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54534436/get-the-value-of-a-child-node-from-a-list-of-nodes-xml-xpath-c-sharp/54535074#54535074

Comment: Why do you think any LINQ will make this any better? It just iterates the collections the same way unless you provide some different logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It will add to `result` all items from `specificCollection`. Then for each item in `defaultCollection` it will check whether or not that `Id` already added. And if this is a new Id, item will be added to `result`:

```
var defaultCollection = ...
var specificCollection = ...

var result = new List<Foo>();
result.AddRange(specificCollection);

var addedIds = new HashSet<int>();
foreach (var foo in specificCollection)
    addedIds.Add(foo.Id);

result.AddRange(defaultCollection.Where(f => !addedIds.Contains(f.Id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `AddRange` function to achieve this as previously pointed out.

```cs
var dc = new List<Foo> { new Foo { Id = 1, Value = 1 }, new Foo { Id = 2, Value = 2 } };
var sc = new List<Foo> { new Foo { Id = 3, Value = 33 }, new Foo {Id = 2, Value = 22} };

var nc = new List<Foo>();
nc.AddRange(sc);
nc.AddRange(dc.Where(c => sc.All(s => s.Id != c.Id)));
```

now the `nc` list contains the following

[image]